# Warning: Use of undefined constant content - assumed 'content' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php

someone tell me where the error is.

hi, someone tell me where the error is.

hi, someone tell me where the error is.

**default.php**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="starter-template" style="padding-top: 100px;">
        <?= content; ?>      
      </div>
    </div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require '../app/Autoloader.php';
App\Autoloader::register(); 


if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $p = $_GET['p'];
}else{
    $p = 'home';
}

ob_start();

if($p==='home'){
    require '../pages/home.php';

}elseif($p==='single'){
    require '../pages/single.php';

}

$content=ob_get_clean();

require '../pages/template/default.php';
```

**home.php**

```
<h1> I am in home page </h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?= content; ?>` replace with  `<?= $content; ?>`